# setBackgroundColor on a layout inside a ViewFlipper does not fill entire screen

Tags: android, android-layout, background-color

I am trying to set the background of an absolute layout that is inside a ViewFlipper. What i get is shown on this image. The blue part does not fill the entire screen, it has a white part on the right side and on the bottom. I made this white part yellow so it is more visible.

[image]

When I use the same code to a layout that is not inside a ViewFlipper it works fine.

The XML code:

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/view_flipper_id"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="6dip" >

<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</AbsoluteLayout>

<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondary_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</AbsoluteLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
```

Where I change the background color:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewFlipper viewFlipper= (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.view_flipper_id);
    AbsoluteLayout mainLayout=(AbsoluteLayout)viewFlipper.getChildAt(0);

     mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255));
}
```

thaks for any help in advance

Comment: I would change `AbsoluteLayout` for some other layout and test again.  `AbsoluteLayout` has been deprecated for a long time and will not have been maintained or fixed for many releases now.  You should not be using it.

Comment: have you tried to remove the layout_margin on the ViewFlipper?

Comment: Ok, but i need the AbsoluteLayout because i need to put widgets dynamically on any part of the screen, do you know if i can do that with any other layout?

Comment: android:gravity="center" did not work

Comment: removing the layout_margin worked, i feel dumb, thaks very much

Comment: I did android:layout_gravity="center" with the margin and it did not work here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the margin for the `ViewFlipper` to 6dp, which means that the inner layouts will leave 6 pixels to the parent View. This means that setting the background for the inner layouts will not affect those 6 pixels.

Simply remove this line:

```
android:layout_margin="6dip"
```